# Update an object from a list of destination derived classes with an object from a list of derived source classes using a generic converter

Tags: c#, generics

I have a list of source classes derived from a base source class and a list with destination classes derived from a base destination class. There is only one destination class corresponding to a source class. I want to make a generic converter which updates an existing destination object, given his corresponding source object.

Updated completely:

I have the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        S1 newItem = new S1()
        {
            Age = 11,
            Name = "John"
        };

        D1 oldItem = new D1()
        {
            Age = 10
        };

        //there is an item in a database which is of D1 type. This convertor receives an object S1 in order to update the D1 item.
        // the rule is that Sx updatates Dx (where x is 1,2,3,4,5...)
        Convertor<S1, D1> convertor = new Convertor<S1, D1>(newItem, oldItem);

        S2 newItem2 = new S2()
        {
            City = "London",
            Name = "Lynda"
        };

        D2 oldItem2 = new D2()
        {
            City = "Paris"
        };

        Convertor<S2, D2> convertor2 = new Convertor<S2, D2>(newItem2, oldItem2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class SourceDomain
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    internal abstract void SetItem<Y>(Y oldItem) where Y : DestinationDomain;
}


public class S1 : SourceDomain
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    internal override void SetItem<Y>(Y oldItem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("here I want to update the age of oldItem (10) with the new value (11)");
        //oldItem.Age = Age;
    }
}

public class S2 : SourceDomain
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    internal override void SetItem<Y>(Y oldItem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("here I want to update the city of oldItem Paris with the new value London");
        // oldItem.City = City;
    }
}

public class DestinationDomain { }
public class D1 : DestinationDomain
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class D2 : DestinationDomain
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Convertor<X, Y> where X : SourceDomain where Y : DestinationDomain
{
    protected X item;
    protected Y oldItem;

    public Convertor(X newObject, Y oldObject)
    {
        item = newObject;
        oldItem = oldObject;

        //here I want to call, depending of item type, the proper method, not the base one.
        item.SetItem(oldItem);
    }
}
```

}

`SourceDomain` and `DestinationDomain` are base classes and there are a lot of derived classes for each of them `S1`, `S2`, `D1`, `D2`, etc.

This converter receives two classes as types and two objects of that classes and tries to update the destination item of type Y with source item of type X.

In the above example, I want to change update the age of the D1 oldItem variable with `11`, and the City oldItem2 with the `"London"` value, but I cannot access that properties in `SetItem method`.

Comment: So you want to update values in an object of a type derived from Y, by using the data of from an object of a type derived from X? I find the question somewhat ambigious, could you provide more "fake" code, describing in it what you want to get? and what part does not work for you?

Comment: That's right @Mohammed Noureldin

Comment: I edited my comment a bit, please take a look at it

Comment: I edited the post for more clarity

Comment: This code is missing so much that it can't compile. It calls methods that don't exist and passes arguments that aren't expected. If you were to create a version of this that compiles in your local IDE and insert that into your question then it would be much easier to work with.

Comment: @ScottHannen I had updated completely. Sorry for the first appearance. I had wrote on the phone.

Comment: *"Derived class S1 Overrides, but here I want to work with D1 type not Y"*: The only things the compiler knows about the hypothetical type `Y` there is that it must derive from `DestinationDomain`, and it must have a parameterless constructor. Therefore, give `DestinationDomain` virtual or abstract methods that do whatever you need done there.

Comment: Also, can you explain what `ref` means to you? Did you put it on that parameter because you just hoped it might help somehow?

Comment: @EdPlunkett ref is used because oldItem is retrieved from database and must be only updated if any change. I'm trying to figure out what solution you have proposed, but i don't get it.

Comment: @MSD561 Delete `ref`. Delete it, delete it, delete it, everywhere you use it. Don't ever use it again until you research *and fully understand* what `ref` actually means. But first: **What do you want to do with `oldItem` in SetItem()?** Tell me in detail, and don't leave out any details. Be very thorough and complete. Don't give me one word or two words. I need to know absolutely everything you want to do with it so I can explain how to do it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Updated completely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194254/discussion-between-msd561-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be done with a combination of inheritance and generics, and we'll make the two work together with generic type constraints.

Here are the requirements as I understand them:

You've got some data you want to copy from Source to Destination; one kind of data has an Age, one has a City, maybe another has a Poodle or a SwimmingPool. We'll define an interface that says: "This is a data object which can copy its own properties from another object of the same type", and we'll put all our data in little classes which know how to copy themselves. The "I can copy things like me" interface doesn't know what properties will be copied; it just requires the concrete class to implement a method that knows those details internally. As far as this example goes it could be a base class, but my assumption is the “copyability” isn’t the core indentity of these objects. It’s not what they represent; it’s just one thing we need to be able to do with them along the way.

The other things we need are a "source thing", and a "destination thing". A source thing just needs to provide a data object that can be copied. A destination thing just needs to receive a data object that can be copied.

You confused yourself by trying to mix up the sources and destinations with the data items. If you're going crazy trying to make your class do two contradictory things at once, try breaking it up into two classes that each does one thing.

You never do anything with your SourceDomain Name property, so I won't either. If you need to, I'll leave that as an exercise.

```
public interface ICopyable<T>
{
    void CopyFrom(T other);
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newItem = new SourceDomain<Person>
        {
            Item = new Person { Age = 11 },
            Name = "John"
        };

        var oldItem = new DestinationDomain<Person>
        {
            Item = new Person { Age = 10 }
        };

        //there is an item in a database which is of D1 type. This convertor receives an object S1 in order to update the D1 item.
        // the rule is that Sx updatates Dx (where x is 1,2,3,4,5...)
        Convertor<Person> convertor = new Convertor<Person>(newItem, oldItem);

        var newItem2 = new SourceDomain<Location>()
        {
            Item = new Location { City = "London" },
            Name = "Lynda"
        };

        var oldItem2 = new DestinationDomain<Location>()
        {
            Item = new Location {  City = "Paris" }
        };

        Convertor<Location> convertor2 = new Convertor<Location>(newItem2, oldItem2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class SourceDomain<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set;  }
}

public class DestinationDomain<T> where T : ICopyable<T>, new()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public T Item { get; set; }
    public void CopyItemFrom(T other)
    {
        if (Item == null)
        {
            Item = new T();
        }
        Item.CopyFrom(other);
    }
}

//  A person is a thing which can turn itself into a copy of another Person. 
//  You could define a class Wombat : ICopyable<Locomotive>, if you wanted to be 
//  able to convert Locomotives to Wombats. You'd just add another CopyFrom()
//  overload, public void CopyFrom(Locomotive other). 
public class Person : ICopyable<Person>
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void CopyFrom(Person other)
    {
        Age = other.Age;
    }
}
public class Location : ICopyable<Location>
{
    public String City { get; set; }

    public void CopyFrom(Location other)
    {
        City = other.City;
    }
}

public class Convertor<X> where X : ICopyable<X>, new()
{
    protected SourceDomain<X> item;
    protected DestinationDomain<X> oldItem;

    public Convertor(SourceDomain<X> newObject, DestinationDomain<X> oldObject)
    {
        item = newObject;
        oldItem = oldObject;

        //here I want to call, depending of item type, the proper method, not the base one.
        //newObject.Data = oldItem.Data;
        oldItem.CopyItemFrom(item.Item);
    }
}
```

Homework:

1. Modify this code so `DestinationDomain.CopyItemFrom()` receives the source itself, not the source's item.
2. I think it's better the way I wrote it. Think of reasons why I might have thought that.
3. Seriously, [find out what `ref` does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), and never again use a keyword in your code if you are only guessing about what it might mean. Don't just throw code at the wall, hoping it sticks. You'll get yourself in a lot of frustrating trouble that way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            S1 newItem = new S1()
            {
                Age = 11,
                Name = "John"
            };

            D1 oldItem = new D1()
            {
                Age = 10
            };

            //there is an item in a database which is of D1 type. This convertor receives an object S1 in order to update the D1 item.
            // the rule is that Sx updatates Dx (where x is 1,2,3,4,5...)
            Convertor<S1, D1> convertor = new Convertor<S1, D1>(newItem, oldItem);

            S2 newItem2 = new S2()
            {
                City = "London",
                Name = "Lynda"
            };

            D2 oldItem2 = new D2()
            {
                City = "Paris"
            };

            Convertor<S2, D2> convertor2 = new Convertor<S2, D2>(newItem2, oldItem2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface ICopyable<T>
    {
        void CopyFrom(T other);
    }

    public abstract class SourceDomain
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public class S1 : SourceDomain
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class S2 : SourceDomain
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationDomain { }
    public class D1 : DestinationDomain, ICopyable<S1>
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public void CopyFrom(S1 other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("oldItem.Age " + Age + " new Age; = " + other.Age);
            Age = other.Age;
            Console.WriteLine("oldItem.Age " + Age + " new Age; = " + other.Age);
        }
    }
    public class D2 : DestinationDomain, ICopyable<S2>
    {
        public string City { get; set; }

        public void CopyFrom(S2 other)
        {
            City = other.City;
            Console.WriteLine(" oldItem.City = City;");
        }
    }

    public class Convertor<X, Y> where X : SourceDomain  where Y : DestinationDomain, ICopyable<X>
    {
        protected X item;
        protected Y oldItem;

        public Convertor(X newObject, Y oldObject)
        {
            item = newObject;
            oldItem = oldObject;

            //here I want to call, depending of X type, the proper method, not the base one.
            oldItem.CopyFrom(item);
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```